# How to get polygons from connected line segments

Tags: javascript, python, algorithm, polygon, line-segment

I have a list of connected line segments. How to get the polygons.

```
let lines = [
    [10, 10, 200, 10],
    [10, 10, 10, 200],
    [10, 200, 200, 10],
    [200, 10, 390, 10],
    [200, 10, 390, 200],
    [390, 10, 390, 200],
    [10, 200, 10, 390],
    [390, 200, 390, 390],
    [10, 390, 390, 390],
    [200, 10, 200, 200],
    [10, 200, 200, 200],
];
```

Sample code visualisation:

[image]

```
// poly 1 would be something like this.
poly1 = [
    [10, 10],
    [200, 10],
    [10, 200],
];
```

Comment: You could build a Doubly Connected Edge List (DCEL) from your line arrangement and extract the faces. Here's a Javascript [implementation](https://github.com/yubowenok/LineArrangement), with a link to a cool demo.

Answer (score 2):

I'd structure the solution like this:

1. Go through each element in `lines` and match one line with the other, e.g. element 1 and 2 would match in [10,10]
2. Go through each pair of lines retrieved from 1. and seek through `lines` for a third line that matches the pair of lines unmatched start/end points. E.g. element 1 and 2 would have unmatched start/end points in [200,10] and [10,200] respectively, this would match with element 3.

Codewise I think the best structure is:

- One function `matchCoordinates(coordinateA,coordinateB)` that takes two coordinate pairs and returns boolean match.
- One function `matchLines(lineA,lineB)` that takes two elements from `lines` and utilizes `matchCoordinates` to find matching lines
- One function `findMissingLine(lineA,desiredLine)` that returns boolean if `lineA` is the same as `desiredLine`, here I would include the edgecase that e.g. element 3 in `lines` is both [10, 10, 200, 10] and [200, 10, 10, 10]